# Is `auto x = f()` better than `T x = f()`?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, object-slicing

In another topic someone suggested using

```
auto x = f();
```

instead of

```
T x = f();
```

(if the signature of `f` is `T f()`). They pointed out this prevents silent object slicing if someone happens to change `f` to `U f()`, where `U` descends from `T`.

It makes sense to me, but there might be other things in play that I am missing. So, which is better and why?

Comment: You may want to read [Herb Sutter's GotW #94 (Almost Always Auto)](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best advantaes of using `auto` in that context is, as Herb Sutter noticed at [*Almost Always Auto*](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), that `auto` makes the usage of an API more mantenible. That is, the API can be modified/refactored without any necesary change in client code.
For example:

### API v1.0

```
template<typename T>
T* abstract_factory::create();
```

### API v2.0

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> abstract_factory::create();
```

#### Usage (Without auto)

```
 Foo* instance = abstract_factory::create<Foo>();
```

#### Client updates API library to v2.0

```
 Foo* instance = abstract_factory::create<Foo>(); //TYPE ERROR!!!
```

#### Update using `auto`

```
 auto instance = abstract_factory::create<Foo>(); //OK! type infered to std::shared_ptr<Foo>
```

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks "the API can be modified/refactored without any necesary change in client code." is a bad thing?

Comment: If things go ahead with a need to recompile, it's because the new thing you got from the new API has the same _duck type_ anyway, and therefore you shouldn't need to change the original code, unless your original code depended on a particular implementation or type (which should be avoided in most cases). In the latter case, you should specify the required type (e.g. `auto x = TypeINeed(f());`). Herb Sutter's article that was posted argues that well

Comment: Sorry, I meant "If things go ahead withOUT a need to recompile [...]"